# Как можно автоматически делать посты в ВК?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Я спарсил с сайта текст в массив на Python, как мне автоматически этот текст запостить в группу ВК?
Вот код:

```
pre_news = []
for info in cut_info:
    pre_news.append({
        "title": info.find("h2", class_="story__title").find_next("a").get_text(),
        "text": info.find("div", class_="story__text").get_text(),
    })
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Пример оттуда:

```
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+71234567890', 'mypassword')
vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()

print(vk.wall.post(message='Hello world!'))
```

Comment: это выложит пост в группу?

Comment: Конкретно этот код постит вроде как на свою стену. Там есть примеры как запостить в группу. Если нет, то у ВК есть открытый api, в котором сто процентов есть методы для постинга в группу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Попробую найти.

Comment: [Здесь](https://vk.com/dev/publications?f=2.%20%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) есть метод для постинга записей из внешнего приложения (python скрипта в нашем случае)